# Compare Time in a Linq Entity Framework Query

Tags: entity-framework

How do I do entity framework Linq query that compares time? For example I want to find all bookings that occured between 1pm and 3pm.

Answer (score 0):

```
var filteredItems = context.Bookings.Where(b => SqlFunctions.DateName("hh", item.DateTime) >= 13 && SqlFunctions.DateName("hh", item.DateTime) < 15)
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to find the bookings between 1:30pm and 3:30pm?